# Web Api route configNot Working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these 2 configs:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "CustomRate1",
          routeTemplate: "api/CustomRate/{action}/{idCustomRate}",
          defaults: new { controller = "CustomRate" }
    );


    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "CustomRate",
                  routeTemplate: "api/CustomRate/{action}/{idCountry}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "CustomRate" }
                );
```

However, only one of them works at a time. If I put CustomRate before the route works, but CustomRate1 does not, the reverse also happens, if I put CustomRate1  on top CustomRate  does not work. Any suggestions

Currently in my controller I have

```
[HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
 public CustomRateListReturnType GetCustomRateListByCountry(long idCountry)
{

}

[HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
public BaseReturnType DesactivateCustomRate(long idCustomRate)
{

}
```

I am currently using these two calls
http://127.0.0.1/quotesystemserver/api/CustomRate/GetCustomRateListByCountry/5

and

http://127.0.0.1/quotesystemserver/api/CustomRate/DesactivateCustomRate/3

Comment: Are you having 2 different action methods?

Comment: Yes, I have :-

[HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
public CustomRateReturnType SaveCustomRate(CustomRateBusiness customRate)
{

}

[HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
public BaseReturnType DesactivateCustomRate(long idCustomRate)
{

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok What I did is as follows:-

My config is now as follows:-

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
 name: "CustomRate1",
 routeTemplate: "api/CustomRate/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { controller = "CustomRate" }
);
```

My controller contains:-

```
[HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
public CustomRateReturnType GetCustomRateListByCountry(long id)
{

}

[HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
public BaseReturnType DesactivateCustomRate(long id)
{

}
```

Comment: still the same issue? why u need [HttpOptions]. you have decorated with [httppost] and you are calling through get?

Answer (score 0):

Just have one route. 
The placeholders {action} and {id} will take the values what you pass in the URL.
If you call http://127.0.0.1/quotesystemserver/api/CustomRate/GetCustomRateListByCountry/5
,the route will take action as GetCustomRateListByCountry and id as 5.
Whatever you give the name to the placeholder { } doesnot matter. It is just the placeholder name. The value comes from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

use attribute routing, it gives more clearer picture of the custom routes for any person who is developing the application for rest you can use config routes:

Decorate your controller with

```
[RoutePrefix("api/CustomRate")]
```

And your action methods as follows

```
HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
[Route("GetCustomRateListByCountry/{idCountry:long}]
public CustomRateListReturnType GetCustomRateListByCountry(long? idCountry)
{

}

[HttpPost()]
[HttpOptions]
[Route("DesactivateCustomRate/{idCustomRate:long}]
public BaseReturnType DesactivateCustomRate(long? idCustomRate)
{

}
```

Add the below code in webapiconfig.cs

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();